# Executing a list of methods with list of objects

Tags: python, class, jython

I have got a list of Objects of the same class and want to execute a list of methods one by one.

F.e.

```
objectlist = [ obj1, obj2, obj3, ...]
methodlist = [ obj(?).returnstring(para1), obj(?).returnint(para2,subpara1), ...]

for i in range(len(objectlist)):
    for n in range(len(methodlist)):
        value = obj[i].methodlist[n]
        print(value)
```

I just have this dirty workaround:

```
objectlist = [ obj1, obj2, obj3, ...]
i = 0
methodlist = [ objectlist[i].returnstring(para1), objectlist[i].returnint(para2,subpara1), ...]

for i in range(len(objectlist)):
    for n in range(len(methodlist)):
        value = obj[i].methodlist[n]
        print(value)
```

Well ... it works, but I get stomachache with this solution.

Is there a nicer way to do this?

Greets,

zonk

Comment: Your workaround does **not** work, it only will call **on the first element**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your workaround does **not** work, it only will call on the **first** element. Since `i = 0`, it will **evaluate** instantly.

You can use *lambda-expressions* for this:

```
objectlist = [ obj1, obj2, obj3, ...]
methodlist = [lambda obj:obj.returnstring(para1), lambda obj:obj.returnint(para2,subpara1), ...]
```

So here `methodlist` contains a list of lambda expressions of the form:

```
lambda obj:obj.returnstring(para1)
```

A lambda expression is an *anonymous function* that here takes as input a parameter `obj` and *returns `obj.returnstring(para1)` on that object. It is thus more or less equivalent to:

```
def afunction(obj):
    return obj.returnstring(para1)
```

Now you can simply iterate over the list of objects and methods and call the lambda expression with the parameter and do something with the result. Like:

```
for i in range(len(objectlist)):
    for n in range(len(methodlist)):
        value = methodlist[n](obj[i])
        print(value)
```

But it is more elegantly to loop immediately over your elements like:

```
for obji in objectlist:
    for methn in methodlist:
        value = methn(obji)
        print(value)
```

Comment: Well, it still "works". Yes I call the first element in my list, but later "i" get a new value in the for loop. In my project I check before this point if the list even exists. But whatever, it's wrong & dirty of me. :^)
I never had to do anything with lambda stuff before, but I'll take a try tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

a bit less dirty, but still not great

```
objectlist = [ obj1, obj2, obj3, ...]
i = 0

for m_obj in objectlist:
    i=i+1
    methodlist = [ objectlist[i].returnstring(para1), objectlist[i].returnint(para2,subpara1), ...]

    for m_method in methodlist:
        value = m_obj.m_method()
        print(value)
```

this uses python's "nice" looping features, and also redefines your methods for every object (not necessary here, since all obji are of the same class; but still good practice)

Comment: Well, normally I have to do with C or C++ stuff, so it's a little bit odd for me to loop this way. ^^